# Having issue with the parameter that need to include both values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, parameters

I'm running to this issue which I think it's related to the parameter. I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I'm 90% sure the parameter in the query is not correct. So, there are two forms (Short Form and Long Form).

- Short Form is just Short Form
- Long Form includes the Short Form and Long Form together

Here is my query

```
SELECT  distinct
pid_respiratorfit.FormDimDocId,
pid_respiratorfit.EnrollDate,
pid_respiratorfit.Id,
pid_respiratorfit.FormDimDocInstanceId,
Patient.NEDID,
Patient.PFIRSTNAME,
Patient.PLASTNAME,
dimInputDetail.displayStatement AS DisplayStatement,
dimInputDetail.statement AS Measure,
dimInputDetail.structureID AS StructureID,
dimInputAnswers.Value AS Answers,
dimInputs.comments AS Findings,
dimInputs.ID as FindingsID,
dimDocSectionLayout.SectionTitle AS SectionTitle,
dimDocSectionLayout.[order] as dimDocSectionLayoutOrder,
dimDocSectionLayout.sectionID,
dimDocInputLayout.[order]
FROM     pid_respiratorfit INNER JOIN
                  dimInputDetail RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dimDocInputLayout ON dimInputDetail.ID = dimDocInputLayout.questionID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dimDocSectionLayout ON dimDocInputLayout.sectionID = dimDocSectionLayout.sectionID AND dimDocInputLayout.surveyID = dimDocSectionLayout.surveyID INNER JOIN
                  dimInstance ON dimInstance.dimDocID = dimDocSectionLayout.surveyID ON pid_respiratorfit.FormDimDocId = dimInstance.dimDocID AND
                  pid_respiratorfit.FormDimDocInstanceId = dimInstance.ID INNER JOIN
                  Patient ON pid_respiratorfit.PTIDNum = Patient.PTIDNUM RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dimDocMetaInfo ON dimInstance.dimDocID = dimDocMetaInfo.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dimInputsDialogue RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                  dimInputs ON dimInputsDialogue.DimInputsID = dimInputs.ID ON dimInputDetail.ID = dimInputs.inputID AND dimInstance.ID = dimInputs.dimDocInstanceID AND
                  dimDocMetaInfo.ID = dimInputs.dimDocID AND dimDocInputLayout.usageCount = dimInputs.usageCount LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dimInputAnswers ON dimInputs.ID = dimInputAnswers.dimInputsID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dim_fileUploads ON dimInstance.ID = dim_fileUploads.dimDocInstanceID AND dimDocInputLayout.usageCount = dim_fileUploads.usageCount AND
                  dimInputDetail.ID = dim_fileUploads.inputID AND dimDocMetaInfo.ID = dim_fileUploads.dimDocID
WHERE  pid_respiratorfit.Id = @respfitID AND dimDocSectionLayout.sectionID = @sectionID
ORDER BY dimDocSectionLayout.[order], 
         dimDocInputLayout.[order];
```

[image]
If the record has the Short Form only and the parameter for section ID will be looking for value "1", the form will be printed successfully. However, if the record has the Long Form (which also includes Short Form) and that is the one I' having trouble right now, the section ID will be looking for both values "1" and "2". But as of now, I dont know how to add the parameter that includes both Short Form and Long Form and keep the Short Form value alone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, so I'll put up a simplified version and you can clarify if I'm wrong.

I think you have a table with a list of questions, with each question flagged with a "form", either Short or Long, which I'll represent as 1 and 2 respectively. Each question has an "order" it should be printed in, some text for the question, and a bunch of other details that go along with these but don't affect selection. You pass in a parameter saying if you want short form or long form, with Short being all questions tagged "1" and Long being all tagged 2 plus all tagged 1 as well.

If that's the essence of your problem, there are several options that will work, the best depending on your exact situation

```
--This is your parameter, could be passed into a Stored Procedure or whatever
DECLARE @FormLen INT = 1 --1 = ShortForm, 2 = LongForm

;with cteSampleData as (--Build some sample data
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('Taking medicine', 1, 1) 
        , ('Used Respirator', 2, 1), ('Lost vision', 3, 1), ('Back Injury', 4, 1)
        , ('High altitude', 5, 2), ('Harsh chemicals', 6, 2), ('Side jobs', 7, 2)
    ) as FormDef(QuestionText, QOrder, TargetForm)
)SELECT * 
FROM cteSampleData
WHERE (TargetForm = @FormLen --Grab line when @FormLen = 1 and TargetForm = 1 
        --or @FormLen = 2 and TargetForm = 2 
    OR (@FormLen = 2 AND TargetForm = 1)) --Grab line when @FormLen = 2 AND TargetForm = 1, 
        -- adding in Short Form questions when LongForm is specified
    -- AND (other conditions, like CustomerID = @Customer) --Use to add in other requirements, note that the above
        --MUST be in parenthesis!
--ALTERNATE FORM
--WHERE TargetForm <= @FormLen
ORDER BY QOrder, TargetForm
```

If you can represent TargetForm with an integer, and you want longer forms to include all "shorter" forms, the best choice is the

```
WHERE TargetForm <= @FormLen
```

form, it's simple and easily scales if more depth layers are defined later.

If you must use a non-integer representation, you're probably better off with the OR format

```
WHERE (TargetForm = @FormLen --Grab line when @FormLen = 1 and TargetForm = 1 
        --or @FormLen = 2 and TargetForm = 2 
    OR (@FormLen = 2 AND TargetForm = 1)) --Grab line when @FormLen = 2 AND TargetForm = 1,
```

which doesn't scale as well but is insensitive to the representation of TargetForm